# Please explain this ambiguity in C

Tags: c, random

When I am compiling this program I am getting some random number as output.. In Cygwin the output is 47 but in RHEL5, it is giving some negative random numbers as output.
 Can anyone tell me the reason?
Code:

```
main()
{
printf("%d");
}
```

Comment: Turn the warning level on your compiler up all the way. Then the compiler will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @larsmans: and `-Werror` if you're feeling particularly warning-free.

Comment: what is that a trick question from an interview? or how did the idea come to you to write such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program provokes *undefined behavior* since it does not follow the rules of C. You should give `printf` one argument per format specifier after the format string.

On common C implementations, it prints whatever happens to be on the stack after the pointer to `"%d"`, interpreted as an integer. On others, it may send [demons flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: +1, but it's wrong. Printing whatever happened to be on the stack is a part of the nasal daemon launch procedure.

Comment: It's ok (for sufficiently small values of ok) to give more parameters than format specifiers, as in `printf("%d\n", n, x++); /* print n and increase x */`. The extra arguments are evaluated and ignored.

Comment: @pmg: I said "should", not "must". And I don't think it's ok to write programs like that, unless you're competing in the IOCCC :)

Comment: +1 for the nasal demons, wish more people understood that part about undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2):

It is [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior).

On 3 counts:

- absence of prototype for a function taking a variable number of arguments
- lying to `printf` by telling it you are sending 1 argument and sending none
- absence to return a value from `main` (in C99 a `return 0;` is assumed, but your code definitely isn't C99)

Anything can happen.

Comment: 4th count: The question is tagged `C`, so the OP needs `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

printf expects a second argument, so it reads whatever happens to be on the stack at that location. Essentially it's reading random memory and printing it out.